# How to compare custom label value in controller with '!=' operator

Tags: apex

**Controller:**

```
public List<SelectOption>FlagPickList{
        get{
            List<SelectOption> FlagOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
            FlagOptions.add(new SelectOption('All',Label.None));
            FlagOptions.add(new SelectOption('True',LabelTRUE));
            FlagOptions.add(new SelectOption( 'False',Label.FALSE));   
            return FlagOptions;
        }
    }
```

these labels are contain 'dutch' translation. visualforce will return Flag1 as value for this picklist.
i want to compare in controller,

```
if(string.valueOf(Flag1)!=Label.None)
{
//condition
}
else{
//condition
}
```

it's working fine for English user. but when it's a Dutch user ,unable to compare in if condition and going to else part.

Comment: Use `System.debug()` statement to debug the value you are getting for `Flag1` and `Label` in your code.

Comment: when it's dutch user, values are coming in dutch language for 'All'. but unable to compare it in if condition and entering inside if

Comment: What are you getting in the `label` and `flag` in case of Dutch language?

Comment: Flag1 coming with translated value for 'All' and label.none in English at the time of checking

Comment: Then use of the options presented in the posted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't compare the label in this case; you're literally trying to check English versus Dutch values. You can change **one** of the two places where this disconnect occurs.

## Option 1

Use English in your code:

```
if(Flag1!='All') { ...
```

## Option 2

Use only the labels:

```
FlagOptions.add(new SelectOption(Label.None,Label.None));
...
```

Comment: you r right for adding FlagOptions but when I am checking with '!=' operator it's considering label but when using '==' operator it's considering Value.   I have to check like: if (Flag !='All' && Flag !='translated one') considering label. otherwise I have to write if (Flag=='All') considering value. My confusion  is why in case of '!= ' operator it's considering label and in case of '==' operator it's considering Value?

Comment: @IndrajitKolay The first parameter of SelectOption specifies the value. This value is what must match Flag1. You don't need to check both values. You simply need to get the values to agree with each other. There's no "magic" happening here, it's simply a confusion of the label value with the English value. Use one or the other, consistently, and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help@sfdcfox :). it's working fine now.